# how to enable heideltime printdetail?

Tags: java, nlp, uima, heideltime

how can i enable Printdetail while running or debugging Heideltime in eclipse?
in logger class in package de.unihd.dbs.uima.annotator.heideltime.utilities; it says:

```
/**
 * Logger class to facilitate a centralized logging effort. Upon initialization of
 * the HeidelTime annotator, the verbosity (printDetails) should be set; any kind of
 * output should be done using either the printDetail()-methods for DEBUG-Level,
 * conditional output or the printError()-methods for ERROR-Level, unconditional
 * output.
 * @author julian zell
 *
 */
```

I initialize like this:

```
HeidelTimeStandalone heidelTime = new HeidelTimeStandalone(
                Language.getLanguageFromString("auto-azeri"),
                DocumentType.NEWS,
                OutputType.TIMEML,
                ".\\conf\\config.props", POSTagger.NO);
```

can anyone give me an example please?